# Can we implement CRUD spring boot and postgresql with kafka

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Can kafka be implemented with spring boot + postgresql ? is there an additional process, for example if we insert data into the database how to use kafka? then when calling data from database should I put into kafka first and then the get api just call from kafka not from database ? is this correct to use kafka ?

then when the user calls the save api then I have to retrieve it from the database at the same time so that the data in kafka is also updated ?

Comment: You might have to explain the use case here. What is the purpose of application? Why do you want to use Kafka?

Comment: For example, when we call the getCompanyDetail API, the flow of kafka is that we will create a topic and become a consumer in the API to get the response from the API. can this process be done?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumption would be separate from any database action

You can use Kafka Connect framework, separately from any Spring app to write data from Postgres to/from Kafka using a combination of Debezium and/or Confluent's JDBC connector

Actions from the Spring app can use KafkaTemplate or JDBCTemplate depending on your needs

Comment: Is it possible to create a getCompanyDetail api where the flow is to create a topic first (which contains the company id) then send it to the topic and then get a response from the consumer on that one api. thanks

Comment: You ideally should already have a topic created beforehand for any events you'll produce or consume. That being said, Spring webflux should be able to do something like that, yes. Like I said, though, Kafka Connect after the producer is generally more useful than processing the database actions in your own code. Then the "consumer" API for getting a company is reading from a database, not a Kafka topic